# Верстка сайта, расположение списка

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

[image: наглядный пример]
Ситуация следующая: при большом экране 4 связных блока выстраиваются в линию все замечательно, далее при всех разрешениях все хорошо, но в разрешении от 795 до 982 идет такой баг => 4 элемент списка переходит на другую строку становится огромным, а хотелось чтобы он переходил, как на второй части скриншота с 3 элементом и они равнялись по размеру

Comment: ну дак верстку в студию!

Comment: @teran там обычный список из card'ов с информацией
конструкция примерно вот такая:
`<div> card </div>
<div> card </div>
<div> card </div>
<div> card </div>`
Просто не могу правильно понять как из завернуть, чтобы нормально адаптировались

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div> card </div> 
  <div> card </div> 
  <div> card </div> 
  <div> card </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (здесь это было не очевидно) — ДЕМО: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/vft6ye84/